# How to make 3 bottom sheet with bottom navigation like google map

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bottom-sheet, android-bottom-nav-view

I wonder how to make 3 bottom sheet above navigation bottom, when you touch the navigation, the bottom sheet will refresh the layout and change different bottom sheet directly, like this

[image: this is google layout]

Comment: you can follow this link --->https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create 3 different bottomnavigationviews and add it in a same relative layout parent with same layout params. Show/hide the visibility of the bottomview based on the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ViewPager` and add fragments in `ViewPager` through adapter